# Fractional anti-derivatives and derivatives of the logarithm

Tags: calculus, limits, fractional-calculus

Anti-derivatives and derivatives of the natural logarithm are well defined until we attempt to evaluate the fractional derivative and anti-derivatives.

The background to this problem was that I was trying to evaluate fractional derivatives of $\frac1x$, which is usually given as $D^n\frac1x=\frac{\Gamma(0)}{\Gamma(-n)}x^{-1-n}$, but that is defined only for $n=0$ and nowhere else.  You can define it for $n\in\mathbb N$, but this is not the best definition one could have.  ($D^n$ is the $n$th derivative with respect to $x$)

I have the general $n$th anti-derivative ($I^n$) of the natural logarithm as

> $$I^n\ln(x)=\frac{x^n\left(\ln(x)-\int_0^1\frac{t^n-1}{t-1}dt\right)}{\Gamma(n+1)}$$

Proved by induction: $\frac d{dx}I^n\ln(x)=I^{n-1}\ln(x)$, and holds true for $n=1$.

I have this [graphed on Desmos.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/du8q1f9hzx)  (I really like that it has an integral feature.  And if it is too slow, click the little circles on the right to turn off those functions.)

While this is a great formula, it doesn't really work for derivatives ($D^n=I^{-n}$), or at least, Desmos stops graphing at $n=-0.99$, but before that, it appears as though $\lim_{n\to-1}I^n\ln(x)=\frac1x$

I attempted to evaluate it for $n=-1$

$$\frac1x=D^1\ln(x)=I^{-1}\ln(x)=\lim_{n\to-1}\frac{x^n\left(\ln(x)-\int_0^1\frac{t^n-1}{t-1}dt\right)}{\Gamma(n+1)}$$

If you try to directly substitute, you get an indefinite form, so I attempted to do a limit method instead.  I would like to apply L'Hostpital's rule, but I don't quite know how to deal with either the numerator nor the denominator.

I have found that

$$I^{1/2}\ln(x)=\frac{2\sqrt x\left(\ln(x)-2+\ln(4)\right)}{\sqrt\pi}$$

The $2-\ln(4)$ is wolframalpha's evaluation of $\int_0^1\frac{t^{1/2}-1}{t-1}dt$

From here, you can differentiate like normal to get $D^{(2n-1)/2}\ln(x)$, $n\in\mathbb N$.

More importantly, if the limit from above is correct, then my formula works for $I^{-n}\ln(x)$ with $n\in\mathbb N$ and I can finally define what $D^n\frac1x$ is equal to!

So the question:

> How can we evaluate the limit: $\lim_{n\to-1}I^n\ln(x)$?  What does it equal?
>
> Is the fractional derivative of the natural logarithm and $\frac1x$ already known?  I've made posts on this before, and it doesn't appear many people have tackled this problem.  [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1674338/the-nth-integral-of-lnx-and-fractional-derivatives) and [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1675088/some-pecular-fractional-integrals-derivatives-of-the-natural-logarithm).  Both have received little attention.  Attempting to use regular fractional derivative formulas are extremely messy, so I could not actually use them.  If someone more experienced can, that'd be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complex order differintegral appears as equation (9) with positive real part of the order (i.e., all derivatives) in Tu, S-T., D-K. Chyan, & H.M. Srivastava, "[Certain Operators of the Fractional Calculus and Their Applications Associated with the Logarithmic and Digamma Functions](https://dspace.library.uvic.ca/bitstream/handle/1828/1656/DMS-715.pdf?sequence=1)", 1995.    Analytic continuation to the rest of the plane appears as (16) there.

Comment: Ah, so $D^\mu\ln(x)=\frac{x^{-\mu}\left(\ln(x)-\gamma-\psi(1-\mu)\right)}{\Gamma(1-\mu)}$... ok, thanks.  This was helpful.  Can different methods to computing fractional differintegrals result in different results?

Comment: Wow, I just graphed that, and it turns out that the result is the same.  Thank you.  https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hk9h7zsu5b

Answer (score 1):

Note: As is usually the case with Fractional Derivatives, there is also not "the Fractional Derivative". They differ depending on the method of derivation used and the type of Differential Operator.

#### Calculation Via "Euler Method"

Leonhard Euler came up with a nice method for some [Fractional Derivatives](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalDerivative.html) (see Euler's Approach). He has sorted the derivatives of the function by order and is trying to find a pattern in it. He then tried to transfer this pattern from integer orders to fractional ones, which I always affectionately call the "Euler method". If we try that with the [Natural Logarithm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalLogarithm.html) $\ln\left( \cdot \right)$ we probably only get a special case of [Faà di Bruno's Formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FaadiBrunosFormula.html) in most cases.

But it is possible to find a generalized formula for the integrals: *The following generalization for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is not from me. I got it form [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/187130/1103878) from another [user](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/38725/cyclochaotic). Respect to [cyclochaotic](https://user:38725) for that. He proved it too.*
$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{I_{z}^{0}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= \ln\left( z \right)\\
\operatorname{I_{z}^{1}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= z \cdot \left( \ln\left( z \right) - 1 \right)\\
\operatorname{I_{z}^{2}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= z^{2} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{2} \cdot \ln\left( z \right) - \frac{3}{4} \right)\\
\operatorname{I_{z}^{3}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= z^{3} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{6} \cdot \ln\left( z \right) - \frac{11}{36} \right)\\
\operatorname{I_{z}^{4}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= z^{4} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{120} \cdot \ln\left( z \right) - \frac{25}{288} \right)\\
\operatorname{I_{z}^{5}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= z^{5} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{2} \cdot \ln\left( z \right) - \frac{137}{7200} \right)\\
&\cdots\\
\operatorname{I_{z}^{n}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= \frac{z^{n}}{\left( n! \right)^{2}} \cdot \left( n! \cdot \ln\left( z \right) + \cos\left( n \cdot \pi \right) \cdot S_{n + 1}^{\left( 2 \right)} \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$
where $S_{\cdot}^{\left( \cdot \right)} = s\left( \cdot,\, \cdot \right)$ is a [Stirling Number Of The First Kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheFirstKind.html).

$S_{z}^{\left( 2 \right)}$ is a realy good special case of [Stirling Numbers Of The First Kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheFirstKind.html), for it has a useful relation to the [Harmonic Numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html) $H_{n}$ given by $S_{n}^{\left( 2 \right)} = \left( -1 \right)^{n} \cdot \left( n - 1 \right)! \cdot H_{n - 1}$, which is so useful because of its relation to the [Digamma Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html) $\psi_{0}\left( \cdot \right)$ given by $H_{n} = \gamma + \psi_{0}\left( n + 1 \right)$ where $\gamma$ si the [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html). With this we can generalize the term and get: $H_{n - 1} = \gamma + \psi_{0}\left( n \right)$
$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{I_{z}^{n}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= \frac{z^{n}}{\left( n! \right)^{2}} \cdot \left( n! \cdot \ln\left( z \right) + \cos\left( n \cdot \pi \right) \cdot S_{n + 1}^{\left( 2 \right)} \right)\\
\operatorname{I_{z}^{n}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= \frac{z^{n}}{\left( n! \right)^{2}} \cdot \left( n! \cdot \ln\left( z \right) + \cos\left( n \cdot \pi \right) \cdot \left( -1 \right)^{n} \cdot \left( n - 1 \right)! \cdot H_{n - 1} \right)\\
\operatorname{I_{z}^{n}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= \frac{z^{n}}{\left( n! \right)^{2}} \cdot \left( n! \cdot \ln\left( z \right) + \cos\left( n \cdot \pi \right) \cdot \left( -1 \right)^{n} \cdot \left( n - 1 \right)! \cdot \left( \gamma + \psi_{0}\left( n \right) \right) \right)\\
\operatorname{I_{z}^{n}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= \frac{z^{n}}{\left( \Gamma\left( n + 1 \right) \right)^{2}} \cdot \left( \Gamma\left( n + 1 \right) \cdot \ln\left( z \right) + \cos\left( n \cdot \pi \right) \cdot \left( -1 \right)^{n} \cdot \Gamma\left( n \right) \cdot \left( \gamma + \psi_{0}\left( n \right) \right) \right)\\
\operatorname{I_{z}^{n}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= \frac{z^{n}}{\left( \Gamma\left( n + 1 \right) \right)^{2}} \cdot \left( \Gamma\left( n + 1 \right) \cdot \ln\left( z \right) + \left( -1 \right)^{n} \cdot \left( -1 \right)^{n} \cdot \Gamma\left( n \right) \cdot \left( \gamma + \psi_{0}\left( n \right) \right) \right)\\
\operatorname{I_{z}^{n}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= \frac{z^{n}}{\left( \Gamma\left( n + 1 \right) \right)^{2}} \cdot \left( \Gamma\left( n + 1 \right) \cdot \ln\left( z \right) + \Gamma\left( n \right) \cdot \left( \gamma + \psi_{0}\left( n \right) \right) \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$
where $\Gamma\left( \cdot \right)$ is the [Complete Gamma Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html).

But the last of these equations is also defined for non-natural $n$. This allows us to generalize:
$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{I_{z}^{\alpha}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= \frac{z^{\alpha}}{\left( \Gamma\left( \alpha + 1 \right) \right)^{2}} \cdot \left( \Gamma\left( \alpha + 1 \right) \cdot \ln\left( z \right) + \Gamma\left( \alpha \right) \cdot \left( \gamma + \psi_{0}\left( \alpha \right) \right) \right)\\
\end{align*}
$$

But we shouldn't forget the constants that come with indefinite integration (assuming $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ or $\alpha > 0$):
$$\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{I_{z}^{\alpha}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= \frac{z^{\alpha}}{\left( \Gamma\left( \alpha + 1 \right) \right)^{2}} \cdot \left( \Gamma\left( \alpha + 1 \right) \cdot \ln\left( z \right) + \Gamma\left( \alpha \right) \cdot \left( \gamma + \psi_{0}\left( \alpha \right) \right) \right) + \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\left\lfloor \alpha \right\rfloor}\left[ c_{k} \cdot x^{k - 1} \right]\\
\end{align*}
$}$$
where all $c_{k}$ are some constants and $\left\lfloor \cdot \right\rfloor$ is the [Floor Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FloorFunction.html).

Unfortunately, this function has singularitys at non-positiv integers $\alpha$.

#### Calculation Via Series Expansion

Another well-known and frequently used method to differentiate a function fractionally is simply to differentiate the series expansion of this function with addends from functions that are easier to differentiate fractionally.
The [Natural Logarithm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalLogarithm.html) $\ln\left( \cdot \right)$ has a wonderfully simple series expansion ([Taylor Series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TaylorSeries.html) around $z = 1$) given by $\ln\left( 1 + z \right) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{\left( -1 \right)^{k + 1}}{k} \cdot z^{k} \right]$ ([Mercator Series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MercatorSeries.html)) aka $\ln\left( z \right) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{\left( -1 \right)^{k + 1}}{k} \cdot \left( z - 1 \right)^{k} \right]$.

If we now use the property $\operatorname{D_{x}^{\alpha}} = \operatorname{I_{x}^{-\alpha}}$ we'll get:
$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{I_{z}^{\alpha}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= \operatorname{I_{z}^{\alpha}}\left[ \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{\left( -1 \right)^{k + 1}}{k} \cdot \left( z - 1 \right)^{k} \right] \right]\\
\operatorname{I_{z}^{\alpha}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \operatorname{I_{z}^{\alpha}}\left[ \frac{\left( -1 \right)^{k + 1}}{k} \cdot \left( z - 1 \right)^{k} \right] \right]\\
\operatorname{I_{z}^{\alpha}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{\left( -1 \right)^{k + 1}}{k} \cdot \operatorname{I_{z}^{\alpha}}\left[ \left( z - 1 \right)^{k} \right] \right]\\
\operatorname{I_{z}^{\alpha}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{\left( -1 \right)^{k + 1}}{k} \cdot \operatorname{D_{z}^{-\alpha}}\left[ \left( z - 1 \right)^{k} \right] \right]\\
\end{align*}
$$

Via using $\operatorname{D_{x}^{\alpha}}\left[ \left( x - 1 \right)^{m} \right] = \frac{\Gamma\left( m + 1 \right)}{\Gamma\left( m - \alpha + 1 \right)} \cdot \left( x - 1 \right)^{m - \alpha}$ (for $m > 0$) where $\Gamma\left( \cdot \right)$ is the [Complete Gamma Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html) we'll get: *You can read a step-by-step derivation of the formula used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4678041/1103878).*
$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{I_{z}^{\alpha}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{\left( -1 \right)^{k + 1}}{k} \cdot \operatorname{D_{z}^{-\alpha}}\left[ \left( z - 1 \right)^{k} \right] \right]\\
\operatorname{I_{z}^{\alpha}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{\left( -1 \right)^{k + 1}}{k} \cdot \frac{\Gamma\left( k + 1 \right)}{\Gamma\left( k + \alpha + 1 \right)} \cdot \left( z - 1 \right)^{k + \alpha} \right]\\
\end{align*}
$$

But we shouldn't forget the constants that come with indefinite integration (assuming $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ or $\alpha > 0$):
$$\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{I_{z}^{\alpha}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{\left( -1 \right)^{k + 1}}{k} \cdot \frac{\Gamma\left( k + 1 \right)}{\Gamma\left( k + \alpha + 1 \right)} \cdot \left( z - 1 \right)^{k + \alpha} \right] + \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\left\lfloor \alpha \right\rfloor}\left[ c_{k} \cdot x^{k - 1} \right]\\
\end{align*}
$}$$
where all $c_{k}$ are some constants and $\left\lfloor \cdot \right\rfloor$ is the [Floor Function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FloorFunction.html).

But this series expansion converges very very slowly.

This function is defined for $\alpha = -1$. In fact, it gives:
$$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{I_{z}^{-1}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{\left( -1 \right)^{k + 1}}{k} \cdot \frac{\Gamma\left( k + 1 \right)}{\Gamma\left( k + -1 + 1 \right)} \cdot \left( z - 1 \right)^{k + -1} \right]\\
\operatorname{I_{z}^{-1}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{\left( -1 \right)^{k + 1}}{k} \cdot \frac{\Gamma\left( k + 1 \right)}{\Gamma\left( k \right)} \cdot \left( z - 1 \right)^{k - 1} \right]\\
\operatorname{I_{z}^{-1}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{\left( -1 \right)^{k + 1}}{k} \cdot k \cdot \left( z - 1 \right)^{k - 1} \right]\\
\operatorname{I_{z}^{-1}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \left( -1 \right)^{k + 1} \cdot \left( z - 1 \right)^{k - 1} \right]\\
\operatorname{I_{z}^{-1}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \left( -1 \right)^{k - 1} \cdot \left( z - 1 \right)^{k - 1} \right]\\
\operatorname{I_{z}^{-1}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left[ \left( -1 \right)^{n} \cdot \left( z - 1 \right)^{n} \right]\\
\operatorname{I_{z}^{-1}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] &= \frac{1}{z}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Wolfram|Alpha gives the same [Series Expansion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNpCA.png). So:

$$\fbox{$\operatorname{I_{z}^{-1}}\left[ \ln\left( z \right) \right] = \frac{1}{z}$}$$